# Will the Insight seismometer use the deployment of the Heat Flow and Physical Properties Probe as a known impact source for sounding purposes?

Tags: mars, nasa, insight

As the Heat Flow and Physical Properties Probe (**HP<sup>3</sup>**) hammers itself into the Martian soil, it will generate impacts of known intensity. I have not been able to find anything on https://mars.nasa.gov/insight/ that states whether or not the seismometer will use these impacts to perform a SONAR-like survey of the surrounding geology.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Won't the heat sensor probe interfere with the seismometer?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/32354/wont-the-heat-sensor-probe-interfere-with-the-seismometer) - see my [answer](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/32474/20636) in  particular

Comment: It's a good question, closing as duplicate doesn't mean that it isn't, it just helps direct future readers to one or more existing answers. If you find this specific technique interesting (I know I certainly do!) then please consider asking a new question! What kind of sensitivity or resolution is possible for example.